# Is the exponentiated sum of squared norms a valid kernel function?

Tags: kernel-trick

Define $$k(x, y) = e^{-(||x||^2 + ||y||^2)}$$

Is this a valid kernel function?

My guess is yes, with the feature map $\phi(x) := e^{-||x||^2} \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Then $k(x,y) = \phi(x) \cdot \phi(y)$ is continuous, symmetric and positive semi-definite. Is this correct?

Comment: Which part of the demonstration are you uncertain about?

Comment: I'm uncertain whether the above kernel is a valid kernel, in general.